# Scramble (to generate api doc) in production environment

Tags: laravel

I recently discovered [scramble](https://scramble.dedoc.co/) to build API documentation automatically.

It's absolutely brilliant!

There is one thing, however, that I cannot do: authorize access to the document in the production environment.

Indeed, the tool applies the **RestrictedDocsAccess** middleware and voluntarily prevents access in production.

But it is possible to add a gate according to the [documentation](https://scramble.dedoc.co/usage/getting-started). That's what I did. But it still doesn't work.

I also tried to make my own middleware, without success.

And I wonder if it's not because of the very latest version of Laravel (I'm working on 11) and that scramble is not planned for this version?